# Tree node text to be list

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, lists, tikz-trees

How can I change the node text to be a list?

For example, I want to have the following:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]

    \node (Root) {3}
        child {
        node {1}
        child { node {\begin{enumerate} \item Nested item 1 \item Nested item 2 \end{enumerate}} }
        child { node {1} }
        child { node {3} }
    }
    child {
        node {2}
        child { node {3} }
        child { node {2} }
        child { node {5} }
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I got LaTeX Error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Comment: Please post complete code we can compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the contents of the node into a box of some kind. For example, you could use a `minipage` or a `\parbox` or any similar device.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]

    \node (Root) {3}
        child {
        node {1}
        child { node {\begin{minipage}{45mm}\begin{enumerate} \item Nested item 1 \item Nested item 2 \end{enumerate}\end{minipage}} }
        child { node {1} }
        child { node {3} }
    }
    child {
        node {2}
        child { node {3} }
        child { node {2} }
        child { node {5} }
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: boxed node content]